# How can I use 5V devices and sensors with a Fio?

Tags: hardware, arduino

I have a PS/2 barcode scanner that works fine with my Uno and the [PS2Keyboard](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/PS2Keyboard) library. I'd like to hook it up to my [Fio](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardFio) so that I can transmit barcode readings wirelessly, but the operating voltage of the Fio is 3.3V. I tried giving the scanner 3.3V, it will not operate on the reduced voltage.

How can I use 5V devices and sensors on the Fio? Would a [boost converter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_converter) circuit be sufficient?

Comment: I'll be honest, I don't particularly see how a Boost converter is that different from a transistor, other than it uses the same power supply(?) Any chance you could elaborate?

Comment: I edited the question before I saw your answer, I believe you are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my perspective, it seems the only (reasonable) solution is to use a transistor as an amplifier/switch. I'm presuming you know how a transistor works - basically, a current to the base results in a gain between the collector and the emitter - if you don't understand about transistors, you can find out on [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com). This way you can effectively convert your 3.3V signal into a 5V one, so your Fio can interface with the 5V logic.

Answer (score 2):

A boost converter is for supply voltages and not for IO.  So if your supply is only 3.3V and your devices needs 5V, a boost supply will work.

Keep in mind that most devices that run at 3.3V are not tolerant of IO running at 5V.  The ATmega328 is one of those devices.  When VCC is 3.3V the maximum an input can handle is Vcc+0.5V = **3.8V**.

Generally 5V devices do not need modification to receive 3.3V logic.  (It depends on what the thresholds for the two devices are).  However the 3.3V device will need something to shift the IO, like a voltage divider.

If the device uses an open collector (like a PS2 keyboard) for its data line, you may be able to pull-up the signal to the lower voltage.

For example your FIO can, likely, drive the clock signal to the scanner directly.  If the data line uses a pull-up resistor, you can try pulling it up to the 3.3V rail.  Otherwise, you'll need to use a voltage divider.